# How to estimate the difference in viscosity between 2 liquids without lab instruments?

Tags: home-experiment, viscosity

Having 2 liquids I wonder which of the two is more viscous.

I'm not looking at precise values, but something like roughly "twice as viscous".

Without lab instruments, only using kitchen elements, is there a way to estimate roughly the difference in viscosity of 2 liquids?

Comment: Put liquids into two cups. Take clean, matched ball bearings. Time them (or watch them) drop to the bottom of your cups. If not very viscous you may need some tall containers, or less dense (but matched) round objects.

Comment: I think @JonCuster's very good comment should be an answer. The ball's velocity is proportional to 1/viscosity, so you can even get, by timing, a good measure of relative viscosity (i.e. half the speed = twice the viscosity). Proximity to the container walls will also slow the balls, so both containers should be matched in shape/size as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use two identical cups with identical circular holes in their bottoms, both stoppered. Fill both with identical amounts of liquids $1$ and $2$, at identical temperature.

Then remove remove the stoppers and measure the time for the cups to empty.

These times are proportional to the liquids' viscosities.

A variant of this method is to insert a paper straw in the bottom of the cup, as shown below (use bathroom silicone sealant or similar to stem any leaking):

[image: Viscosity cup]

Use a yard stick (shown in green) to make sure $h_1$ and $h_3$ are always the same.

This may provide better resolution,
A simple model can show that the time $\Delta t$ to empty the cup is proportional to the viscosity $\mu$.

According to the Hagen-Poisuelle equation (laminar) flow through a pipe obeys:

$$\Delta p=\frac{8 \mu h_2 Q}{\pi R^4}$$
And with Pascal:
$$\Delta p=\rho g h_1=\rho g y$$
So that:
$$\rho g y=\frac{8 \mu h_2 Q}{\pi R^4}$$
We also know that:
$$Q=\frac{\text{d}V}{\text{d}t}$$
Assume the cup to be cylindrical (not shown that way) with radius $R_{cup}$, then:

$$\text{d}V=-\pi R_{cup}^2 \text{d}y$$
So that:

$$\text{d}t=-\frac{8\mu R_{cup}^2h_2}{\rho g R^4}\frac{\text{d}y}{y}$$
Integrated between $(0, h_1)$ and $(\Delta t, h_1')$ we obtain:

$$\boxed{\Delta t=\frac{8 R_{cup}^2 h_2}{\rho g R^4}\mu\ln{\Big(\frac{h_1}{h_3}\Big)}}$$

So this suggests strongly that, all other things being equal:
$$\boxed{\Delta t \propto \mu}$$

---

If the cup isn't cylindrical but a truncated cone (as is often the case and as pictured) then $R_{cup}$ is a function of $y$, i.e. $R_{cup}(y)$.

Thus $\text{d} t$ becomes:

$$\text{d} t=-\frac{8 h_2}{\rho g R^4}\mu \frac{R_{cup}(y)^2 \text{d}y}{y}=-\frac{8 h_2}{\rho g R^4}\mu I$$

$$R_{cup}(y)=ay+b$$
where:
$$a=\frac{R_1-R_0}{h_1}\text{ and }b=R_0$$
with $R_0=R_{cup}$ at $y=0$ and $R_1=R_{cup}$ at $y=h_1$

So:
$$I=\frac{(ay+b)^2}{y}\text{d}y=\Big(a^2 y+2ab+\frac{b^2}{y}\Big)\text{d}y$$
$$I_{det}=\int_{h_1}^{h_3}I\text{d}y=\frac{a^2}{2}(h_3^2-h_1^2)+2ab(h_3-h_1)+b^2 \ln\Big(\frac{h_3}{h_1}\Big)$$

$$\boxed{\Delta t=\frac{8 h_2}{\rho g R^4}\mu \Big(\frac{a^2}{2}(h_1^2-h_3^2)+2ab(h_1-h_3)+b^2 \ln\Big(\frac{h_1}{h_3}\Big)\Big)}$$

Comment: Between your answer and @JoCuster's comment (both using gravity) are they equivalent in terms of accuracy (in Jo's comment, by measuring the time it takes for the balls to reach the bottom)? Something that needs to be said as well: both liquids have to be at the same temperature...

Comment: Yes, both methods should be *comparable* wrt accuracy. And yes, both liquids have to be at the same temperature.

Comment: I've added a variant with some proof.